# Watched directive attribute changed in $emit

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that's watching a controller property which is modified within an event handler.

The code looks something like this:

```
vm = this;
vm.someProperty = false;

// Event listeners
$scope.$on('controller.loaded', function (event, data) {
    // data.someProperty === true.
    angular.extend(vm, data);
});
```

I then have a directive that uses this property:

```
<body mydirective="someController.someProperty">
```

and an `$observe` on the property value inside the directive:

```
attrs.$observe(attrs.mydirective, function (value) {
```

When I make changes to `vm.someproperty` from within the event listener, the `$observe` handler is never triggered. My guess is that the change is outside of an angular scope that would allow it to register the change.

Do I need to trigger something in this case to make sure all observed properties and their dependencies are re calculated?

Comment: if are doing attrs.$observe you need to use interpolation, `mydirective={{someController.someProperty}}`

Comment: i dont think that it can interpolate from path like `someController.someProperty` ,did your directive share  `$rootScope` with contoller ?

Comment: you can use rootscope to watch property without specializing the controller name

Comment: It didn't work for me when interpolating the property however changing from `attrs.$observe` to `scope.$watch` works exactly as I want.